# Get conversation list using Sinch API & iOS SDK

Tags: ios, chat, instant-messaging, sinch

I have to develop a messaging app and I came across this Sinch messaging SDK. I had downloaded the iOS SDK and tried the Sinch Instant Messaging sample app. I was able to send messages and get messages. But I need to know:

1. Can I get the conversation list using Sinch SDK with latest message for each conversation to show in list?
2. How can I differentiate the incoming chat messages from different users. In the sample I see only one chat messages screen which populates all the messages from different users. So, do we have any property in Sinch SDK that differentiates the conversations?
3. Is there any possibility to create group name, group image for group chat? And how will Sinch API will possibly maintain these group chat and single chat message?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, Think of us as a delivery mechanism for messages, not a mailbox.
2. Look at the `senderid` in the messages, that will differentiate who is sending.
3. You can implement that feature by `SendMessageWithHeaders`, but Sinch IM is not really channel discussion group, its more well suited for multirecipient messages.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the group name, group image for group chat etc features more easily.  Many API SDK's resources are available in an internet market.  For instant communication between users.
Refer to this, you may get an idea: 
https://www.quora.com/What-SDKs-APIs-are-viable-for-implementing-instant-messaging-between-clients-Android-iOS-and-web